# Yahoo placefinder api stopped working

Tags: json, geolocation, yahoo-api

Yahoo placefinder api has stopped working.
I know that this is a deprecated version, and have been discontinued by Yahoo.

Below is my url.

http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?postal=122001&country=India&appid=XXXXXXXX&flags=j

I would just like to know free substitute to this api.

In my application when user enters pincode, this URL pre-populates his city, state and country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using YQL still seems to work OK: [http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.placefinder%20where%20postal%3D%22122001%22%20and%20country%3D%22india%22&diagnostics=true](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20geo.placefinder%20where%20postal=%22122001%22%20and%20country=%22india%22&diagnostics=true)

And this as well, http://gws2.maps.yahoo.com/findlocation?pf=1&postal=122001&country=india

Comment: any idea how to get the geocode based on lat,long not postal code?

Comment: nope this no longer works either